# Eval() syntax in C++

Tags: c++, function, class, parameters, declaration

I have to make a class that holds data and then give it an eval() method.

However, I cannot get the eval() to work. This is how far I am:

in h file:

```
class MyClass {
private:
double K;
double T;

public:
void eval();
};
```

in cpp file:

```
void MyClass::eval()
{
double MyFunction();
}
```

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: What is that eval function supposed to do? Why are you declaring another function inside it?

Comment: In this example your problem is `double MyFunction();` declared inside `eval()`. You cannot declare functions inside functions. Lambdas are exception to this though.

Comment: It looks like (and sounds like) calling `eval()` is supposed to call another function. Where does that other function come from?

Comment: I am coming from python, so I am very much a novice in C++ syntax. I am supposed to create a class that holds the relavant data e.g. "k" and give it an eval() method that evaluates t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you mean something like the following

```
class MyClass {
private:
double K;
double T;

public:
void eval( double f() );
};

void MyClass::eval( double f() )
{
    // ...
    double result = f();
    //...
}
```

Or

```
class MyClass {
private:
double K;
double T;

public:
void eval( double f( double, double ) );
};

void MyClass::eval( double f( double, double ) )
{
    // ...
    double result = f( K, T );
    //...
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass 
{
private:
    double K;
    double T;

public:
    MyClass( double K, double T ) : K( K ), T( T ) {}
    void eval( double f( double, double ) );
};

void MyClass::eval( double f( double, double ) )
{
    double result = f( K, T );

    std::cout << "result = " << result << '\n';
}

double sum( double x, double y )
{
    return x + y;
}

int main() 
{
    MyClass obj( 10.10, 20.20 );

    obj.eval( sum );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
result = 30.3
```

Comment: Yes, and it is not working.

Comment: @KalsuLutter See my updated post. Your "not working" has nothing common with your original question.

Comment: This approach does work. -Kalsu what do you mean when you say it isn't working? Does it not compile? Are you getting an error? How are you using it? As a shot in the dark are you inheriting from an interface and calling eval on a number of different kinds of objects? Perhaps you need eval to be defined as a virtual function?

Comment: I could now replicate the above example. I will try to modify the example to my problem. Thanks a million for the help so far!

Comment: @KalsuLutter You should close this question and ask a new one if you have some other problem with the presented code.

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. I will repost my question, as your code is working, but for my own code, it does not. I really appreciate the help so far!